# Disable scrolling while navbar is extended

Tags: html, css

It seems like I'm asking a lot of questions today...but that's the fun with playing around with code I guess :p

So for this my issue is that when the page has a long vertical length and the navbar is active (by pressing the hamburger icon and sliding out the navbar) there is nothing to stop the user from scrolling down and taking the navbar with it. It's not terrible, but ideally I'd like to disable scrolling while the navbar is open as otherwise it's very odd having a floating navbar coming down the screen with you.

Now, a quick google search tells you (in many different ways) that the potential solution to this issue is to add position:fixed and overflow:none to the html,body tag or wrapper in order to disable scrolling....but while that does work, it disables scrolling entirely whether the navbar is out or not which is not what I want. What I do want is to disable scrolling when the navbar is out...when the navbar retracts back the user should be able to scroll down as normal

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav_drawer" name="" value="">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <label for="nav_drawer" class="nav_drawer_toggle">&#x2261;</label>

    <header class="logo">
      <h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">Title</a></h1></header>

    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <div id="announcements_box">
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      <p>TTT</p>
      </div>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html,body{
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}


#wrapper{
   margin: 0 auto;
   min-width: 320px;
   max-width: 1600px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
   color:#FEBC11;
   text-align: center;
}

header #nav_logo{
   border-bottom: none; 
   background-color: transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#FEBC11;
}

header.logo h1{
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: .5rem; 
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 1rem;
   padding-top: 1rem;
   background-color: #333;
}

.logo{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
}

.navigation{
   position:fixed;
   top: 3.25rem;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: -190px;
   z-index: 0;
   background-color: white;
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation li{
   width: 10rem; 
}

.navigation li .nav_link{
   display: block;
   color: white;
   background-color: blue;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: .5rem;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
}

.navigation li a:hover{
   color: red;
}

.navigation li a.current{
   background-color: pink;
}

#nav_drawer{
   display: none;

}

#nav_drawer:checked + #wrapper .navigation{
   left: 0px;
}



.nav_drawer_toggle{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: none;
   border: 0;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-top: .4rem;
   margin-right: 1rem;
   font-size: 2rem;
   z-index: 1;
}

.nav_drawer_toggle:hover{
   color:#FEBC11;
}


#wowslider-container1{
    z-index: -999;
}
```

This jsfiddle shows what I am referring to. Just click the hamburger icon and scroll down to see: https://jsfiddle.net/7zon9vsz/

Comment: just add the properties when the menu is visible and remove when it is hidden. With javascript it is a fairly trivial task. You can google for it and you will find lot of examples of both: adding css properties and trigger the event of menu visible or not

Comment: I knew I forgot to mention something. I'm doing this without javascript as I assume it's quite possible. If not, that would explain why I have so much trouble with it xD but I'm trying not to

Comment: @user2501783 Have you considered to always have the menu so the behaviour is not so strange and you can close your navbar when you want? Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zon9vsz/6/) of what I mean.

Comment: I did, but I was forgoing it in place of having it disallow the user from scrolling down. It seems more natural to me that way than letting them just scroll down and down and down with the navbar open. Yes, this could have been done in js (I know), but I'm trying to make anything crucial to the structure of the site to be javascript-free. I'll add plenty of js for fun effects later. As far as things go...your solution does work and it was one I was floating around. If the other way is not an option...I'd happily accept this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Changing `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` on the `.navigation` allows you to scroll with the nav open and it will remain in its position. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zon9vsz/8/).

Comment: Not quite. Yours is similar to Error404's above except his sticks to the top of the screen and thus comes down as well when you scroll while yours simply sticks the navbar to the title bar. Both solutions are fine, but not what I was really asking about. As I mentioned, I've floated around those in my head but I was explicitly trying to make it so that the user cannot scroll down while the navbar is extended outward (without js)

Comment: I think what you are looking for may be impossible to do without JavaScript. Stopping the scrolling can be done with `overflow: hidden` on the `body` but as far as I know there is no way to have it toggle along with your navigation menu.

Comment: Then I'll leave it here and go with the other options instead. Thanks for the help guys :) It's a pain to do things without js, but you start to see the inside and out of css which is something xD